# How could I create a dataset with data about music such as songs, albums, artists, and their meta data such as when they were published/established?

Tags: python, dataset, google-colaboratory, spotipy

I am creating an app that will need to access a very large dataset.  The dataset will need to have data about music, films, locations, etc.

I have started with populating my database with music data and I found the spotipy API.  Does anyone know if the spotipy API would be a good method for populating my dataset with music?  I have experimented with it and found that the search method has a limit of 50 results, so that does not help my situation.

I found in the examples in their documentation you can do this to retrieve all albums of a specific artist:

```
birdy_uri = 'spotify:artist:2WX2uTcsvV5OnS0inACecP'
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=CLIENT_ID)

results = sp.artist_albums(birdy_uri, album_type='album')
albums = results['items']
while results['next']:
    results = spotify.next(results)
    albums.extend(results['items'])

for album in albums:
    print(album['name'])
```

I got this working and it prints this:

```
Young Heart
Beautiful Lies
Beautiful Lies
Beautiful Lies (Deluxe)
Beautiful Lies (Deluxe)
Fire Within
Fire Within
Fire Within (Deluxe)
Fire Within (Deluxe)
Fire Within (Deluxe)
Live in London
Birdy
Birdy
Birdy
Birdy
Birdy (Deluxe Version)
```

But when I try the same thing with a different artist, for example led zeppelin like this:

```
ledZep_uri = "spotify:artist:36QJpDe2go2KgaRleHCDTp"
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=CLIENT_ID)

results = sp.artist_albums(ledZep_uri , album_type='album')
albums = results['items']

while results['next']:
    results = spotify.next(results)
    albums.extend(results['items'])

for album in albums:
    print(album['name'])
```

I get a traceback error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-451d92017532> in <module>
      6 
      7 while results['next']:
----> 8     results = spotify.next(results)
      9     albums.extend(results['items'])
     10 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/spotipy/client.py in _auth_headers(self)
    234             return {}
    235         try:
--> 236             token = self.auth_manager.get_access_token(as_dict=False)
    237         except TypeError:
    238             token = self.auth_manager.get_access_token()

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_access_token'
```

I understand it has a problem with my access token but I don't understand why it didn't throw error with the original birdy example.  I would imagine if there's a problem with my access token, I wouldn't have been able to do either.

Anyways, I am curious if spotipy would work for populating my database?  If anyone has experience with spotipy, or knows a different method of populating my database (maybe web scraping?) I would really appreciate some insight here.

Thanks

Comment: Check Spotify API license, I think what you are trying to do is against their license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, Two items were wrong.

#1 Credential Setting : detail information in [here](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.22.1/#client-credentials-flow)

From

```
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=CLIENT_ID)
```

To

```
auth_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)
```

#2 spotify variable

From

```
results = sp.artist_albums(ledZep_uri , album_type='album')
```

To

```
results = spotify.artist_albums(ledZep_uri , album_type='album')
```

Because you did create `spotify = spotipy.Spotify()`

so API calling by `spotify.artist_albums()` is correct not.`sp.artist_albums()`

This is demo code

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

CLIENT_ID='<your client ID>'
CLIENT_SECRET='<your client Secret>'

auth_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)
spotify  = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)

artist_uri = 'spotify:artist:2WX2uTcsvV5OnS0inACecP' # Birdy
# artist_uri = 'spotify:artist:36QJpDe2go2KgaRleHCDTp' # ledZep

results = spotify.artist_albums(artist_uri, album_type='album')
albums = results['items']
artist_name = results['items'][0]['artists'][0]['name']
while results:
    results = spotify.next(results)
    if not results is None:
        albums.extend(results['items'])
        if results['next']:
            results = spotify.next(results)
        else:
            results = None

print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('{:40s} : {:12s} : {:12s} : {:10s}'.format(artist_name +' '+'Album Name' , 'Release Date', 'Total Tracks', 'Album URI'))
print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
for album in albums:
    print('{:40s} : {:12s} : {:12d} : {:10s}'.format(album['name'] , album['release_date'], album['total_tracks'], album['uri']))

print('Total albums Number is {:3d}'.format(len(albums)))
```

Result for Birdy

```
d:\temp\361>python get-album.py
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Birdy Album Name                         : Release Date : Total Tracks : Album URI
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Young Heart                              : 2021-04-30   :           16 : spotify:album:4qsLVZk1UnizpQJBkbFNdx
Beautiful Lies                           : 2016-03-25   :           14 : spotify:album:1UVggFtdVPqHy5WamYFu6w
Beautiful Lies                           : 2016-03-25   :           14 : spotify:album:5wNnopxjgSKVvHTIcBpV8Q
Beautiful Lies (Deluxe)                  : 2016-03-25   :           19 : spotify:album:5TxrdDAUkipqcb4zGnnwkz
Beautiful Lies (Deluxe)                  : 2016-03-25   :           19 : spotify:album:2uNFpEVey5RsxzTdoDmjiz
Fire Within                              : 2013-09-16   :           13 : spotify:album:0r94AFhRLvpfXvha7vx2dK
Fire Within                              : 2013-09-16   :           11 : spotify:album:1JCe9MAwb1aE01UoAwCnOM
Fire Within (Deluxe)                     : 2013-09-16   :           17 : spotify:album:7xvS6C6kW205wbu0fjwqyu
Fire Within (Deluxe)                     : 2013-09-16   :           16 : spotify:album:24f6ycLAjcI8rNYfV6WZvS
Fire Within (Deluxe)                     : 2013-09-16   :           15 : spotify:album:6ig2k0oiH2AXm8MugikskB
Live in London                           : 2012         :            8 : spotify:album:55BQeeBdoCapsI5SZFA3IN
Birdy                                    : 2011-11-19   :           11 : spotify:album:1RmWIBEicywaqVL5re4qbI
Birdy                                    : 2011-11-07   :           13 : spotify:album:7j7ykLBxerILBLBc8AICJS
Birdy                                    : 2011-11-07   :           12 : spotify:album:2dpWqqBl9Faf0Bfo8q4F5u
Birdy                                    : 2011-11-04   :           11 : spotify:album:1WGjSVIw0TVfbp5KrOFiP0
Birdy (Deluxe Version)                   : 2011-11-04   :           14 : spotify:album:3sGzkurA1fvEFqh73sWCVA
Total albums Number is  16
```

Result for ledZep  by enable line 11 and commented out line 10

```
d:\temp\361>python get-album.py
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Led Zeppelin Album Name                  : Release Date : Total Tracks : Album URI
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Complete BBC Sessions (Remastered)   : 2016-09-16   :           33 : spotify:album:6VH2op0GKIl3WNTbZmmcmI
Physical Graffiti (Deluxe Edition)       : 2015-02-24   :           22 : spotify:album:23FJTTzUIUjhmimOE2CTX2
Celebration Day                          : 2012-11-19   :           16 : spotify:album:0kTe1sQd9yhDsdG2Zth7X6
Mothership (Remastered)                  : 2007         :           24 : spotify:album:4wExFfncaUIqSgoxnqa3Eh
How the West Was Won (Remaster)          : 2003-05-27   :           18 : spotify:album:3otvl9PN3kOgk5uwAh1CBL
Coda (Deluxe Edition)                    : 1982-11-19   :           23 : spotify:album:56G9UnPmRifbubzPDJfAyd
Coda (Remaster)                          : 1982-11-19   :            8 : spotify:album:228mANuRrV20jS5DCA0eER
In Through the out Door (Deluxe Edition) : 1979-08-15   :           14 : spotify:album:1jCYuXr0Ujke24z1ymBr5U
In Through the out Door (Remaster)       : 1979-08-15   :            7 : spotify:album:1W5CtQ7Ng0kP3lXyz7PIT2
The Song Remains the Same (Remaster)     : 1976-10-22   :           15 : spotify:album:0ui4S0TZghkf1d1Wz0oWpk
Presence (Deluxe Edition)                : 1976-03-31   :           12 : spotify:album:6vSiY2OVanKKforfEOT2PD
Presence (Remaster)                      : 1976-03-31   :            7 : spotify:album:3uhD8hNpb0m3iIZ18RHH5u
Physical Graffiti (1994 Remaster)        : 1975-02-24   :           15 : spotify:album:0ovKDDAHiTwg4AEjKdgdWo
Physical Graffiti (Remaster)             : 1975-02-24   :           15 : spotify:album:4Q7cPyiP8cMIlUEHAqeYfd
Physical Graffiti (Deluxe Edition)       : 1975-02-24   :           22 : spotify:album:26tH0kjUhkxBEd3ipGkx3Y
Houses of the Holy (Deluxe Edition)      : 1973-03-28   :           15 : spotify:album:7gS8ozSkvPW3VBPLnXOZ7S
Houses of the Holy (Remaster)            : 1973-03-28   :            8 : spotify:album:0GqpoHJREPp0iuXK3HzrHk
Led Zeppelin IV (Deluxe Edition)         : 1971-11-08   :           16 : spotify:album:44Ig8dzqOkvkGDzaUof9lK
Led Zeppelin IV (Remaster)               : 1971-11-08   :            8 : spotify:album:5EyIDBAqhnlkAHqvPRwdbX
Led Zeppelin III (Deluxe Edition)        : 1970-10-05   :           19 : spotify:album:3EaQYGDFE96xbOPxkJNXfX
Led Zeppelin III (Deluxe Edition)        : 1970-10-05   :           19 : spotify:album:4xGEiQ7La4japmGrREeLlw
Led Zeppelin III (Remaster)              : 1970         :           10 : spotify:album:6P5QHz4XtxOmS5EuiGIPut
Led Zeppelin II (Deluxe Edition)         : 1969-10-22   :           17 : spotify:album:58N1RPC3B4mRkjBaug4u3X
Led Zeppelin II (Deluxe Edition)         : 1969-10-22   :           17 : spotify:album:0kQ7ZEH940VZXAfJD4xh2L
Led Zeppelin II (Remaster)               : 1969-10-22   :            9 : spotify:album:58MQ0PLijVHePUonQlK76Y
Led Zeppelin II (1994 Remaster)          : 1969-10-22   :            9 : spotify:album:70lQYZtypdCALtFVlQAcvx
Led Zeppelin (Deluxe Edition)            : 1969-01-12   :           17 : spotify:album:5HNlYbQp7wKbKscWy7ceMp
Led Zeppelin (Deluxe Edition)            : 1969-01-12   :           17 : spotify:album:22BzOOZKYZ2jYYKLpOlnET
Led Zeppelin (Remaster)                  : 1969-01-12   :            9 : spotify:album:1J8QW9qsMLx3staWaHpQmU
Led Zeppelin                             : 1969-01-12   :            9 : spotify:album:3ycjBixZf7S3WpC5WZhhUK
Total albums Number is  30
```